# How to avoid restarting angular live dev server after JIT compilation fails?

Tags: angular

On numerous occasions I have found myself making a typo or using the wrong syntax in my angular template which causes angular to fail the JIT compilation.  This is fine, I will just fix my typo and all will be good right?

Wrong.

Now angular suddenly forgets what directives are and I get errors like: `Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'`

The solution has been to shut down the live dev server and restart it. My computer is slow and this app is large so that means I'm going to be waiting for everything to recompile for a minute or two all because of a typo in the template!

Is there anything I can do to keep the live dev server running and remind angular what directives are? Maybe just recompile the modules or something like that?

Comment: Have you tried AOT?

Comment: I haven't tried aot, would I lose any dev features by using it? I'm not very familiar with it

Comment: It would just compile code at build time instead of using browser in time. Usually it allows to catch some AOT specific errors upfront

Comment: From what I gleaned about AOT is it's for prod because it doesn't recompile right when I make a change in dev which is a feature I would like to keep. Maybe there just is no solution to the problem I described

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it helps to change something in the ts file of the current module or app module to force angular to recompile from higher in the code hierarchy. could also try to ' touch' multiple files at once ( e.g. both app module & feature module ts )

Comment: That makes so much sense. I will have to try it and get back to you

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. I tried touching app.module, a shared module, and the feature module. Although, all I did to 'touch' was type a space then delete it and save, maybe there is something more I can try? Still getting that ngIf is not a known directive of div error

Comment: Which version of angular ? I registered in the past https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/19892 for angular 11.1 (similar to your problem, but typos in scss files) and that was solved (have now 11.2.1)

Comment: running angular 10.1 on this project. I'm doubtful I would be able to convince the rest of my team it's worth upgrading

Comment: I´m afraid Angular´s policy is to restrict bug fixing mainly to the  latest version... was myself not so happy about it because at the  time 11 was just released a month or two.